# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 (update-database error)

Tags: sql, .net-core, migration

I'm trying to create migration and I run: update-database
And I get this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
>   **My connection string: "DefaultConnection": "Data Source= DataSourceName;Initial Catalog=FinancasPessoais;User ID=esantos;Password=**************"**
>   I'm using .net core 3.1

[image: update-database error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the connection string only in appsettings.json, but as of version 3.0 of .netcore it was necessary to create an AppDbContextFactory class in which I declare the connectionstring, but I declared the connectionstring as "DefaultConnection" and I had to declare in the AppDbContextFactory class the complete connection string property.